# Can we use "to jettison" as a synonym for "to throw"

Tags: vocabulary, usage

I was discussing the verb *to jettison* with a native speaker, and my interlocutor gave an example:

> I was jettisoned from the bar. [for bad behavior]

Was this usage sloppy or it is legitimate? My guess is that it is *sloppy*. For me this verb has two feelings: to throw something away (*an action*) which is no longer needed (*a reason*). My friend grasped only the action meaning in his sentence, but the verb has a strong *reason component*, which doesn't fit into the situation. Its usage would be more legitimate in this context:

> I was a bartender at the bar. But the owners decided they didn't need me anymore. I was jettison from the bar.

Comment: It would depend on whether it was a sailor bar.

Comment: Your term *usage usage:* what does this mean?

Comment: A person with bad behavior is not needed in a bar, so I don't see the issue. Yes one can use jettison here. Few things mean *exactly* the same. Other possibilities include *expulsed*, *ejected*, *thrown out*, and even *rejected* if 'given' a new one-off meaning.

Comment: If you wish to say "expulsed" (and to be understood), say "expelled".  Expulse/expulsed is going out of use; it is in dictionaries, but some dictionaries call  it obsolete. Oddly enough, we do still use the noun form "expulsion",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Originally, the verb jettison is used to throw something from a moving ship or plane to make it lighter. But it's also used informally in the sense of "throw away/off"

Please throw the towel to me. You cannot throw the blame on me, he threw his opponent to the ground.

You cannot replace "jettison" with "throw" in the above senses.

You can replace jettison only with "throw off/away", which means to get rid of or discard someone or something (material or immaterial) that is causing harm, or annoying you, or no longer useful to you.

I jettisoned all the old clothes. The plan was jettisoned as it was very expensive.
The captain jettisoned him from the team because of his constant poor performance. It's also correct to say "I was jettisoned from the bar for bad behavior."

Comment: +1 especially for pointing out the difference between *throw* and *throw out* / *throw away*.

Comment: or his girlfriend jettisoned him for not giving her gifts. "His girlfriend jettisoned him for not having enough sex"

Answer (score 3):

The difference between "to throw" and "to jettison" arises *after* the act has occurred.

One can throw an object in a direction, or at another object.  You can throw a ball *at your friend*.  When one jettisons something, one has little to no control over where it goes afterwards.

When used colloquially, as it is used in your examples, "to jettison" gives more of an "anywhere but here" mentality with little care to what happens afterwards, while the potential for direction with "to throw" makes it more neutral.

Answer (score 3):

In America, one gets "thrown out of a bar". This is closer in meaning to jettison than is the simple "throw"  ("thrown from a bar" would rarely be heard).

"Throwing out trash" is virtually identical to jettisoning it, but hardly anyone would say jettison, unless they are on a boat or ship.  Not in regard to trash, nor to a person.

But "throwing out" a person carries a more forceful connotation, and implies a conflict between people, often involving physical force (if the person went willingly, he wouldn't have to be "thrown out".) However, it could be used after the fact, as an exaggeration, if the person was asked to leave, and complied, but later wanted to claim that he stood his ground until physically ejected from the bar.